# Ghostdriver with PHPUnit

Tags: testing, phpunit, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm attempting to use PhantomJS as a browser for PHPUnit Selenium tests.

I've set Selenium running in grid mode, and started phantomjs with webdriver, and registered it to the grid, as in the [GhostDriver Readme](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#register-ghostdriver-with-a-selenium-grid-hub).

When I run a selenium test, it fails with an unknown command error - GhostDriver just doesn't understand what PHPUnit is saying.

```
[ERROR - 2013-05-12T16:23:06.326Z] RouterReqHand - _handle - Thrown => {
  "message": "Request => {\"headers\":{\"Accept\":\"*/*\",\"Connection\":\"Keep-Alive\",\"Content-Length\":\"85\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\",\"Host\":\"127.0.0.1:4444\"},\"httpVersion\":\"1.1\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"post\":\"cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=phantomjs&2=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.testurl.com%2F&\",\"url\":\"/\",\"urlParsed\":{\"anchor\":\"\",\"query\":\"\",\"file\":\"\",\"directory\":\"/\",\"path\":\"/\",\"relative\":\"/\",\"port\":\"\",\"host\":\"\",\"password\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"userInfo\":\"\",\"authority\":\"\",\"protocol\":\"\",\"source\":\"/\",\"queryKey\":{},\"chunks\":[\"\"]}}",
  "name": "Unknown Command",
  "line": 87,
  "sourceId": 139810136032448,
  "sourceURL": ":/ghostdriver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.js",
  "stack": "Unknown Command: Request => {\"headers\":{\"Accept\":\"*/*\",\"Connection\":\"Keep-Alive\",\"Content-Length\":\"85\",\"Content-Type\":\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\",\"Host\":\"127.0.0.1:4444\"},\"httpVersion\":\"1.1\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"post\":\"cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=phantomjs&2=https%3A%2F%2FFtest.testurl.com%2F&\",\"url\":\"/\",\"urlParsed\":{\"anchor\":\"\",\"query\":\"\",\"file\":\"\",\"directory\":\"/\",\"path\":\"/\",\"relative\":\"/\",\"port\":\"\",\"host\":\"\",\"password\":\"\",\"user\":\"\",\"userInfo\":\"\",\"authority\":\"\",\"protocol\":\"\",\"source\":\"/\",\"queryKey\":{},\"chunks\":[\"\"]}}\n    at :/ghostdriver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.js:87",
  "stackArray": [
    {
      "sourceURL": ":/ghostdriver/request_handlers/router_request_handler.js",
      "line": 87
    }
  ]
}
```

This same question was asked and closed unanswered on the [GhostDriver site](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/197%20bug) with the suggestion that it's PHPUnit to blame. That may be the case, but I'm still no nearer to making this work. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using a test class extending `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`. Use `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` instead.

Unfortunately, that's not the end of the story. The syntax of the Selenium-related methods changes when you swap out the base class.

The dated `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` class

- uses the Selenium RC API
- does not support Phantom.js as a browser
- requires the "traditional" syntax [as documented here](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase.tables.seleniumrc-api.setup)
- works fine with code which is generated in Selenium IDE and exported with the help of the "[Selenium IDE: PHP Formatters](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/)" plugin.

By contrast, `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase`

- uses the WebDriver API
- supports Phantom.js
- requires a different set of commands which is not well documented - [this test case](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php) demonstrates it by example, and that's about it
- does not work with code exported from Selenium IDE without an extensive rewrite.

So it is possible to run PHPUnit-driven Selenium tests faster with PhantomJS, but it does come at a cost.

Comment: Thanks - to be honest it's less about speed and more about the fact that Selenium no longer works with Firefox for about the last year, and there's no sign of it being fixed. I've looked for alternatives in desperation. I guess rewriting the tests in this new api is the way forward. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, FF works for me. I'm new to Selenium and have set up the whole shebang last week, so there's no legacy stuff on my machine. Firefox worked out of the box, with the IDE, standalone server, grid node ... even on a Windows host ;)

Comment: Yeah, but there's an ongoing problem with Firefox and the "can't access dead object" error. The page is pretty active with JS creating/replacing elements all over. I can't get through a single webdriver test without it dying with that any more, ever since Firefox 15. This is off topic here though.